# Passing data from Laravel 7 view to controller via Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I need to pass only one value from view to controller,using Ajax(in View home.blade.php).
All solutions are for Laravel 5's and it's not helpful.

Ajax from home.blade.php:

```
$datee="hello";

$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});

 $.ajax({
    type        : 'POST',
    url         : "insert2",
    contentType: "text",
    data:      datee ,
    dataType: 'json'
  });
```

Route:

```
Route::post('/insert2/{datee}', 'EditContdroller@show1');
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

And EditController's method:

```
  public function show1(Request $request){

                         $data= $request->datee;
//some work with $data...
                         return $json_Value;

    }
```

I get Error 404 Post .../insert2 not found.Have you any idea,please?

Comment: Since you are sending the data inside the request, you should remove `{datee}` parameter from your laravel route. Also add a slash before the url in your ajax call `url: "/insert2",` and send the data as object `data: {datee: datee},`.

Comment: thanks, but now I get POST .../insert2 500 (Internal Server Error). Maybe it's because of $.ajaxSetup ?

Comment: You should look in the laravel logs when you get a response with status 500. But I also tell you some other considerations.  Add `X-Requested-With` header to ajaxSetup `$.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') ,
            'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
        }
    });` .Add the csrf token to the data too `data: {datee: datee, _token: $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') }`

Comment: Thanks,I solved it with logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Route::post('/insert2/{datee}', 'EditContdroller@show1');

url:"insert2",
```

Your post route requires additional parameter, but you request without parameter

It should be url: "insert2/something"

Now in Controller the "something" you passed will become variable {datee}

If you want to make the parameter optional, you should add question mark to {datee} making it {datee?} then your AJAX request should work: (I added '?' question mark to the date)

```
Route::post('/insert2/{datee?}', 'EditContdroller@show1');
```

You are passing:

```
data: datee,
```

It doesn't work like this.

To pass the datee, I would recommend doing so:

Remove the {datee} part

```
Route::post('/insert2', 'EditContdroller@show1');
```

In your AJAX request modify your data like this:

```
data: { datee: datee },
```

In your Controller access datee value like this:

```
$datee = $request->input('datee');
```

Comment: tomJo thanks, but now I get  POST .../insert2 500 (Internal Server Error). Maybe it's because of $.ajaxSetup ?

Comment: 500 is a Server Error. You may have some mistakes in PHP code you wrote or similar. AJAX is probably not causing this problem. If I were you, I would debug the code.